# How can I make a server not use the VPN connection for SSH sessions and use its main IP for SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, vpn

I use a VPN service on my Debian server which I connect to remotely using SSH. The problem I'm facing is that when I connect to the VPN on the server I get disconnected from SSH since the server's IP changes to the VPN's IP.

How can I make the server not use the VPN connection for SSH sessions and use its main IP for SSH?

Comment: Cross site posting is not encouraged on the Stackexchange network. Please wait more then 3 hours to see if someone can answer, then flag your [old question](http://serverfault.com/questions/563806/preventing-ssh-to-use-vpn) for migration

Comment: Yes. I have asked that question about 3 hours a go

Comment: What do you mean by _main IP_?

Comment: @MarcusRickert I mean the server's main IP from its connection. The one that the Hosting company gives me to connect to it.

Comment: Then, why would you use a different IP address to connect to your VPN in the first place?

Comment: When I connect to the VPN I get disconnected from the ssh session. The VPN gives a dynamic IP and I will not be able to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I need a little more understanding of your setup to answer the questions.

So, Here we go :

=> Where does the IP change ? Is it the Debian Servers IP ?

=> Which VPN service are you using ?

=> Are you using a Layer 3 tunnel which gives you a local ip when you connect to your network?

=> Is the IP of the debian and the IP pool for VPN in the same subnet ?

Please let me know.

Thank you,

Raghav.

Comment: Also, a list of routes before and after the VPN is active would be particularly useful.